# zsh: unknown file attribute in Mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh

I get an error with alias:

ln -s (which nvim) /opt/homebrew/bin/vim

zsh: unknown file attribute: h

[terminal img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgao7.png)

Comment: Looks like it is missing a dollar sign: `ln -s $(which nvim) /opt/homebrew/bin/vim`. But even that won't work if the destination file exists.  Try an actual alias: `alias vim=nvim`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ln -s "`which nvim`"  /opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

You need to use double quotes around the which command if the result has spaces. The other form also works:

```
ln -s "$(which nvim)"  /opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

An additional way (from Martin Tounoij) is to use equal to expand:

```
ln -s =nvim /opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```